# IBM MQ tuning for tranfer a large number of file

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, file-transfer, large-files, large-data-volumes

I have a project to transfer file using IBM MQ. There are 10000 clients and one data center. The largest file size is almost 8MB. The MQ cluster contains three MQ managers which are at different Windows server. Each MQ manager have 5 channels for client and 5 channel for data center. There are two cases for testing. Clients are evenly distributed to MQ manager in each case. Do not lose any file is the most important thing in these cases.

```
Case 1:
Every client send 50 files to data center at the same time. The files size are between 150KB to 5MB. 
In this case, the sum of file size one client send is almost 80MB.

Case 2 :
Data center send the 10 identical files to every client at the same time. In this case, I create a topic named `myTopic` and 10000 clients subscribe this topic. Data center send 10 identical files to the topic.
```

MQ Mangers have a heavy load. I already set some attribute in IBM MQ:

```
Queue Manager:
    Max handles: 100000
    Maximum message length: 100MB
    Max channels: 10000
    Max channels: 10000
```

Is there any attribute that could increase the performance?

5/11 update:

First, I have modified the situation of case 2 above. I have a data center  server that has a 4 core CPU and 32G RAM. I use 4 clients server to simulate 10000 clients, and each client server has 4 core CPU and 16G RAM.

In case 1, it take about 37 minutes when 1000 clients send files to the data center. There are not enough memory on data center server when data center receive files from 2000 clients. I find there are 20G memory used for buffer/cache. Here is my java code used to receive files:

```
try {
    String filePath = ConfigReader.getInstance().getConfig("filePath");

    MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
    mqMsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
    mqMsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;
    mqMsg.groupId = CMQC.MQGI_NONE;

    int flag = 1;

    while (true) {
        try {
            MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QMGR1");
            int option = CMQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_SUBSCRIPTION | CMQC.MQSO_DURABLE;
            MQTopic subscriber = queueManager.accessTopic("", "myTopic", option, null, "datacenter");
            subscriber.get(mqMsg);

            if (mqMsg.getDataLength() != 0) {
                String fileName = filePath + "_file" + flag + ".txt";

                byte[] b = new byte[mqMsg.getDataLength()];
                mqMsg.readFully(b);

                System.out.println("Receive " + fileName + ", complete time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
                System.out.println("Write " + fileName + ", start time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                Files.write(path, b);
                System.out.println("Write " + fileName + ", complete time: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                flag++;
            }
        } catch (MQException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            if (e.reasonCode != 2033) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            mqMsg.clearMessage();
            mqMsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
            mqMsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;
            mqMsg.groupId = CMQC.MQGI_NONE;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use byte array to read message and write it to disk. Is it possible that the byte array does not release memory and takes 20G memory?

In case 2, I find if I send a 5MB file to `myTopic` that has 1000 subscribers on `MQ manager01`, `MQ manager01` take a lot of time to sync with cluster member. The disks on the MQ servers are very busy. There are another problem: Sometimes I get only 7 seconds to send a 5MB file, sometimes it takes 90 seconds. Here is my java code to send files:

```
try {
    MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QMGR1");
    MQTopic publisher = queueManager.accessTopic("myTopic", "", CMQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_PUBLICATION,
            CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);
    System.out.println("---- start publish , time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ----");
    publisher.put(InMemoryDataProvider.getInstance().getMessage("my5MBFile"));
    System.out.println("---- end publish , time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " ----");
    publish.getPublisher().close();
} catch (MQException e) {
    System.out.println("threadNum: " + publish.getThreadNo() + " publish error");
    if (e.reasonCode != 2033) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Compression on the channel can help if the network connection to the client's is the limiting factor.   That is only a guess since you have not described what the performance is now that you are trying to improve or where the bottleneck currently is.

Comment: Agree w/ @JoshMc on compression-- it uses CPU which is rarely the bottleneck in messaging. How many CPUs? What is the disk perf of the servers? NVME storage will give you a huge lift, with RAID SSD close behind.

Comment: You should try on this site, that is all they do: http://www.mqseries.net/

Comment: You are executing a get loop with no delay and as far as I can tell is opening a new connection to the queue manager each time,  I'm sure this should fail at some point,  do you not receive and MQ exceptions?  Better to create the connection to the queue manager and subscribe to the topic 1 time before the loop,  the in the loop you only do the get and add a wait interval,  the wait is how long MQ will wait for a message on the queue before it returns 2033, you still get the message as soon as it is present on the queue.

Comment: Can you please show a display of the topic object and the durable model queue?

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks. I improve my code. I create the connection when application starts and save it in memory. Sorry, I do not understand "topic object and durable model queue" mean.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

MQ has FTE which transfers files for you.  I think it does it using non persistent messages, so you avoid the disk overhead.

You might try checking your .ini files for  parameters like ClntRcvBuffSize=0
see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016910_.htm). 
0 says use the operating system values.

TCP used to send some data in short packets (64KB chunk), then wait till the packets have been acknowledged, and send more.  If the connection is reliable, then you get higher throughput by sending bigger logical packets, a technique known as Dynamic Right Sizing.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option)

it works best when the connection is long lived and sending  a lot if data.  For example the first few chunks may be 64KB, then increase it a bit to 128KB chunks, eventually up to 100MB ( or more) if needed.

You need to set both ends.

Depending on platform, you can use Netstat replacement ss command to display the various window sizes.

For your QM to QM channels specify a large batchsz and batchlim - though this may make your disk IO worse as the data gets to the remote end faster.